# Cannot get colormatrix and transparency working correctly

Tags: .net, vb.net, transparency, colormatrix

I am working on an RTS style game to learn more about programming using classes, inheritance and interfaces - it is going well, with no major issues.

The problem I am having is with the colormatrix.  I use the the color matrix to add a green or red overlay when placing units on the map, depending on on the validity of the position.  Again this is working fine using the following code (chopped down for clarity).  But I also want to make the image semi-tansparent.

This is the code that I am using, it first makes the unit grayscale, then tints it red, but not make it semi-transparent.

```
Public Overrides Function GetCurrentFrame() As Image
    _AnimationFrame += _AnimationFrameTime
    If _AnimationFrame > 5 Then _AnimationFrame = 0
    Dim CurrentFrame As Image = Nothing

    CurrentFrame = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("dragoon_walk_l_" & Convert.ToInt16(_AnimationFrame).ToString)

    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(CurrentFrame)

    Dim cm As System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix = New System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix(New Single()() _
         {New Single() {0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 0}, _
        New Single() {0.59, 0.59, 0.59, 0, 0}, _
        New Single() {0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0, 0}, _
        New Single() {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, _
        New Single() {0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 1}})

    Dim ia As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes = New System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes()
    ia.SetColorMatrix(cm)
    g.DrawImage(CurrentFrame, New Rectangle(0, 0, CurrentFrame.Width, CurrentFrame.Height), 0, 0, CurrentFrame.Width, CurrentFrame.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia)

    g.DrawImage(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("health" & (Int(20 * (_UnitHealth / _UnitHealthMax)) - 1).ToString), 0, 14)
    g.DrawImage(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("level" & _Level.ToString), 6, 0)
    g.Dispose()
    Return CurrentFrame
End Function
```

For clarification, the question is how can I get my image to be RED and SEMI-TRANSPARENT using a colormatrix.

Answer (score 0):

Been looking at this for 2 days now, and it has just came to me.

The problem is that I was creating the bitmap from the original image, not a blank bitmap. and was returning the image instead of the bitmap :(

This is the solution i used

```
Public Overrides Function GetCurrentFrame() As Image
    _AnimationFrame += _AnimationFrameTime
    If _AnimationFrame > 5 Then _AnimationFrame = 0
    Dim CurrentFrame As Image = Nothing

    CurrentFrame = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("dragoon_walk_l_" & Convert.ToInt16(_AnimationFrame).ToString)

    Dim bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(CurrentFrame.Width, CurrentFrame.Height)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)

    Dim cm As System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix = New System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix(New Single()() _
         {New Single() {.3, .3, .3, 0, 0}, _
        New Single() {0.59, .59,.59, 0, 0}, _
        New Single() {.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0}, _
        New Single() {0, 0, 0, 0.75, 0}, _
        New Single() {0.5, 0, 0, 0, 1}})

    Dim ia As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes = New System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes()
    ia.SetColorMatrix(cm)
    g.DrawImage(CurrentFrame, New Rectangle(0, 0, CurrentFrame.Width, CurrentFrame.Height), 0, 0, CurrentFrame.Width, CurrentFrame.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia)

    g.DrawImage(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("health" & (Int(20 * (_UnitHealth / _UnitHealthMax)) - 1).ToString), 0, 14)
    g.DrawImage(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("level" & _Level.ToString), 6, 0)
    g.Dispose()
    Return bm
End Function
```